# Verification of presence of one text of 2 texts in the page using selenium2library & Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I want to test if the page contains "TEXT1 or "TEXT2".

Page Should Contain  TEXT1  or TEXT2.

Any suggestion how can I do this? Currently I can only check for one text.

Comment: Why can you only check for one piece of text?

Comment: The syntax is "Page Should Contain  text, loglevel=INFO". However my page can contain one of two different texts.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

[`Page Should Contain Element`](http://rtomac.github.com/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Page%20Should%20Contain%20Element)

with a locator

```
xpath=//*[contains(text(),'TEXT1') or contains(text(),'TEXT2')]
```

Comment: My only problem with using xpath is that it works fine on Chrome and Firefox but not on IE

Comment: @HamSmith Could you please be more specific? On IE (and other browsers without native XPath support), Selenium uses the Google-authored [Wicked Good XPath](http://code.google.com/p/wicked-good-xpath/) library which should be perfectly fine. If it isn't, it's either a bug on their side, or a testcase written too optimistically (because, as always, IE makes everything troublesome). Try to resolve your problem, research a bit, and then file a bug or ask here.

Comment: Thanks very much Slanec, I shall do the research and will get back on this forum. Thanks once again for your help.

Comment: You can also use a jQuery locator like
jQuery=#myelement:contains('TEXT1'), #myelement:contains('TEXT2')

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Slanec for the info.

I've also found out another way to solve this just using Robot Framework, it goes like this.

@{VAR1} = Run Keyword and Ignore Error  Wait Until Page Contains  TEXT1
Run Keyword If  '@{VAR1}[0]' == 'FAIL'  Wait Until Page Contains  TEXT2

As the text can be either TEXT1 or TEXT2 depending on the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following three statements:

Pass Execution If   '${var1}' == 'TEXT1'

Pass Execution If   '${var1}' == 'TEXT2'

Fail

Answer (score 0):

```
${t1 present}=  Run Keyword And Return Status  Page Should Contain  TEXT1
Run Keyword If  not ${t1 present}  Page Should Contain  TEXT2
```

After line 1 `${t1 present}` is `True` if TEXT1 is present; if so, the check on line 2 will not be ran. If it's `False`, then the page is checked for TEXT2 - and will fail the case if it's not present.