# Is it possible that keyword 'Element Should Contain' could expect multiple text?

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework, selenium2library

I'm working with RobotFramework and I've created something like that:

```
Element Should Contain    parametersForm:formMessages    Successfully updated
```

In some cases it can return 'No changes on the page.' instead of 'Successfully updated'. Is it possible that this keyword could expect multiple text? I've tried to use XOR and Run Keywords but it fails.

Any advice? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116652/verification-of-presence-of-one-text-of-2-texts-in-the-page-using-selenium2libra

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. one of the answers helped